# com/serial port on windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I am using weighing software on Windows 10 PC where my weighing machine communicates through a COM port. This same software was earlier installed on a Windows XP PC, and was working perfectly.

Since migrating to Windows 10, the  same software is not working correctly. When the software tries to communicate with the weighing machine through the COM port, the first two to three attempts are  working correctly, but after additional attempts the software gets stuck on same screen. I then have to close the software through task manager and restart to work again.

Please help me out with this issue.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about PC hardware

Comment: Okay sir but it can be helpful if anyone can help but it is okay to close if this site doesn't allow for this kind of problem

Comment: What type of COM port (built-in, docking station, add-in card, USB, ...) does the Windows 10 PC have?

Comment: PC is with On board port

Comment: In this case I’d recommend trying a USB adapter. I experienced strange issues with built-in ports in the past, while a USB-COM adapter worked perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try running it in compatibility mode for Windows XP. Right click on the application and select Properties>Compatability>Run this Program in Compatability for>Windows XP. That may be your first shot. After that you may have to see if the component has windows 7 or higher drivers online.

Comment: Sir I have tried windows xp mode but still facing same problem